# How to pronounce "digne" and "na"?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, phonemes

I looked up [*unproduced*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/216564?redirectedFrom=unproduced#eid) in the [Oxford English Dictionary (OED)](http://www.oed.com)¹ and it gave an example quotation from the 1965 edition of John Ireland's 1490 compendium *The Meroure of Wyssdome* ("The Mirror of Wisdom"):

> *It is better and mar digne and excellent to be a substaunce and natur wnproducit na to haue bene maid and producit of nocht.*

I'm trying to learn how to read older forms of English (e.g. Old English, Early Modern English, etc.); but I'm unsure how to pronounce two words in that quote: *digne* and *na*. (I do know what they mean, though.) Based on the OED and [Dictionary of the Scots Language (DSL)](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/) entries², I **think** *na* is pronounced /nay/, but I still have **no idea** of how to pronounce *digne*.

The English dialect these two words are a part of is Middle Scots, [distinct from but roughly concurrent with](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/about-scots/history-of-scots/) Early Modern English.

#### Example Sentences for Context

1. "digne"

> - `OED Entry, sec. 1, quot. 6:` a1450 Knt. de la Tour ii. 5   *It is an higher and more digne thinge forto praise and thanke God.*
> - `DSL Entry, sec. 1, quot. 8:` 1567 G. Ball. 115. *Thy nobill actis digne of remembrance*

2. "na"

> - `OED Entry, sec. 1, quot. 5:` [1533] J. Gau tr. C. Pedersen Richt Vay 94 *Ramember that thy marcie and grace is..greittar nay al our sinnis.*
> - `DSL Entry, sec. 2, quot. 2:` Burgh Laws c. 77 (A).
>     *I graunt I dide other thing na I aucht to doo*

3. Also, "na" has a second meaning—rather than *than*, it can also mean [*nor*](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/na_conj_2). Is this pronounced differently?

> - `sec. 1, quot. 4:` 1398 Acts I. 211/1. *That he sal nocht lette his office na the execucion of it*
> - `sec. 1, quot. 15:` 1453 Reg. Dunferm. 341. *Neuer to be herd in jugement na vtouth*

---

¹ Subscription required.

² Main Entries:

- *Digne*: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52642?redirectedFrom=digne#eid), [DSL](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/digne_adj)
- *Na*: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124740?rskey=hxfOES&result=8#eid), [DSL](http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/na_conj_3)

Comment: See http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?size=First+100&type=headword&q1=digne&rgxp=constrained

Comment: **As I said in the question above**, although it is an English word, it is not a *Middle English* word; it is *Middle Scots*.

Comment: The MED will give  relevant information on the derivation and likely pronunciation of the word *digne*.

Comment: But only for *Middle English* words, I gather, since it's a *Middle English* word you're referring. I'm referring to the *Middle Scots* word.

Comment: Even if one is derived from the other, one could still be pronounced differently from the other.

Comment: Since it's a different dialect, I would sooner assume it is pronounced differently, even if only slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the range of alternative spellings for digne, and the pronunciations of the same word in Icelandic and old Danish, I'd say it was pronounced with a soft 'g', with a sound as the 'y' in "yoke".

deeyne

Using the same deduction, I'd agree with your suggested pronunciation of na:

nay

Comment: How would a "soft g" be pronounced? :/

Comment: The soft g is not used in modern English. It is pronounced like 'y' in "yoke" or "Bayesian"

Comment: I'm not asking about modern English. So why'd you say that?

Comment: And okay. Now how do you pronounce "Bayesian"? Lol.

Comment: I don't pronounce "Bayesian" like this, but the y is fine https://translate.google.com/#en/es/bayesian It's like a downward curl of the tounge. As a matter of fact google's pronunciation of digne isn't too bad, the g isn't as pronounced as it could be, but not bad. Ideally somewhere between https://translate.google.com/#en/es/digne and https://translate.google.com/#en/es/dein%20er (closer to the former)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm still confused. Is there no definite answer for this question...? :I

Comment: I wish I could help you better. If you were here, I'd pronounce it for you :)

Comment: I believe you. :) Thank you **so** much, regardless. =^^=